# html - Eliminating white space after footer

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue in removing the white space after footer.Here is my website: https://www.filterbypass.me/

I tried googling and added `padding:0;` to the footer css but its didn't work.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your footer class

## footer {

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1E1E1E;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'sansationregular';
height: 36px; // ?  36 height
line-height: 40px;  // Here the problem 40 line height
margin-top: 45px;
width: 100%;
```

}

Make it  line-height: 36px; And Think simple...

Comment: Great....Most of the white space is gone but there is still a line of white space after the footer

Comment: u got problem with "AddThis utility frame" it take height 1px .. use firebug addon to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a `height:36px;` to `<div id="footer">` in `combine.css` at line `246`.
This is the problem

Answer (score 0):

in combine.css see footer class

```
footer{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1E1E1E;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'sansationregular';
height: 36px;    /*comment this if you want to keep line-height*/
line-height: 40px;
margin-top: 45px;
width: 100%;
}
```